# Execute PHP artisan test from Controller/Endpoint

Tags: laravel, testing, command, laravel-artisan, php-pest

i want to execute the command "php artisan test" in a endpoint of laravel, i created the Command:

```
<?php 
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

class RunTests extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'run:test';

    protected $description = 'Run tests and display output';

    public function handle()
    {
        Artisan::call('test');
    }
}
```

I added to the kernel.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        Commands\RunTests::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')->hourly();
        // $schedule->command('cache:prune-stale-tags')->hourly();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

And later created the endpoint:

```
Route::get('/test', function(){
    Artisan::call('run:test');
});
```

But this don't work, i tryed to create a command, execute with "exec" function and nothing works, i want to execute all the test that i have calling one endpoint of my routing.

Comment: Why are you trying to execute tests through a URL? Do not do that, firsly because you have CLI, secondly, if you are trying to execute tests on a production server, that is very VERY bad... thirdly, if you are trying to execute tests on a staging server, again, use CLI, you will need to perfect or upgrade your CI/CD. I understand that you want this to work, but the path you are taking is the worst one, so maybe we can help you fix the real issue and it will already prevent you to end up in this situation. Can you explain us why are you trying to run it this way?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call php artisan test directly from the route file and print output ?

```
Route::get('/test', function(){
    // here call test directly and return or dd output
    Artisan::call('test');
    // dd(Artisan::output())
    return Artisan::output();
});
```

Comment: The problem is that if i call Artisan::call('test') an error appears, error message "Undefined array key "argv"", i want to execute php artisan test command in the web.php

Comment: Have you tried running in consile php artisan test ? is it working there ? Also try php artisan optimize if you edit your web route fiel.

Comment: yes, php artisan test it's an artisan command, in console works